# Подключение Windows 7 к Windows XP в сети

Tags: windows, сеть

Пытаюсь объединить два компьютера в сеть. Один под управлением Win7 второй XP. Собственно вопрос заключается в том, как это сделать? Читал, что надо ввести их в одну рабочую группу, - не помогло. Компы друг друга не видят. Сеть нужна, банально для передачи данных (файлов, программ) с одного на другой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. На Windows XP открываете Сетевые подключения и свойства подключения по локальной сети, которое соединяется с Windows 7
2. В свойствах открываете свойства протокола TCP/IP и задаёте настройки в ручную: IP-адрес 192.168.0.1  Маска 255.255.255.0  все остальное - пустые поля.
3. Сохраняете настройки кнопками ОК.
4. На Windows 7 открываете Панель управления - Центр управления сетями и общим доступом. На левой части окна открываете Изменить параметры адаптера и далее свойства подключения по локальной сети, которое соединяется с Windows XP.
5. В свойствах открываете свойства протокола TCP/IP версии 4 и задаёте настройки в ручную: IP-адрес 192.168.0.2  Маска 255.255.255.0 шлюз 192.168.0.1  DNS сервер предпочитаемый 192.168.0.1 остальное - пустые поля.
6. Сохраняете настройки кнопками ОК.
7. Далее, если антивирусный продукты не блокируют работу по сети, то открываете какую-либо папку для общего доступа и сеть должна работать корректно.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно больше сведений о том что вы делаете.
Чтобы перебросить информацию с одного на другой достаточно:

1. Кабель кросс-овер (кабель с одной стороны обжатый Annex-A с другой Annex-B)
2. Папка общего доступа (лучше всего на XP т.к. с 7кой могут возникнуть проблемы)